# There are no Audio devices listed under hardware tab of audio preferences as a result no sound

Tags: sound

lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"

showed the following result

```
20:01.0 Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8290
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
    Memory at <ignored> (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a sound card in your system?  Did it ever work with sound before?

Comment: try killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*  from terminal and logout or reboot

Comment: Are you still having problems?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!