# No sound devices listed under hardware, no sound (one user account specific problem)

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

Update: Loged in as guest and all works as charm. Using my account (administrator) nothing works and i am not able to locate advanced user management options :(

First of all - I use USB headset. there were some troubles with recognition at first, but prestigio were listed under hardware, so i activated it and all worked.

Now after I had to unplug headset and restart lappy, there is no sound devices at all listed under hardware tab. I cant adjust volume there. There is sound from built in speakers, but not from headset.

alsamixer shows me both built in audio card and prestigio (headset). I can choose them, but after esc and leaving alsa it rolls back to "default"

Following this thread,
[There are no Audio devices listed under hardware tab of audio preferences as a result no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70330/there-are-no-audio-devices-listed-under-hardware-tab-of-audio-preferences-as-a-r)
I gathered this info

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 011e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at 98400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

but solution offered (try killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse* from terminal and logout or reboot) gave this result

```
pulseaudio: no process found
rm: remove write-protected regular file `/xxxxxx/.pulse/a336866c5ace61b2c9bc648a0000004f-runtime'? 
rm: cannot remove `/xxxxxxx/.pulse': Directory not empty
```

I am at lost now. Multiple restarts with headset on and off have not yielded any other results. Any suggestions? this is my first time using ubuntu and i am at best confident user in windows, so my own knowledge is quite lacking on issue...

update: 
aplay -l gives this as result.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Failed to stat runtime directory /home/rizjaa/.pulse/a336866c5ace61b2c9bc648a0000004f-runtime: Invalid argument
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC268 Analog [ALC268 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Prestigio [Prestigio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: try with `sudo mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.old` and restart your session.

Comment: mv: cannot stat `/home/rizjaa/.pulse': No such file or directory

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224307/sound-not-working-for-uid-1003-but-working-fine-for-uid-1000

Answer (score 1):

Either @Takkat suggestion worked or in mysterious ways something else worked, but after last restart all audio devices are back and working.

Comment: Sometimes a reboot miraculously cures things ;)

Answer (score 0):

Takkat comment is the answer and solution:

```
sudo mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.old
```

or just

```
sudo rm ~./pulse
```

work perfectly on 12.04 where I've exactly the same problem (audio devices was listed in every account except mine).