# Sound not working for uid=1003 but working fine for uid=1000

Tags: 12.10, sound

Sounds works for uid=1000, but not for the main user on the system, running with uid=1003.  Upon boot, the Ubuntu chime clearly plays.  When the user is logged in, sound test shows no input device.

I looked at several of the previous questions, added the user to audio, video, pulse, pulse-access --- but still no luck.

To recap: This worked perfectly in 11.04, 11.10, 12.04. It works for the default user uid=1000, it does not work for the actual user.   The differing group memberships are mainly for adm, admin, sudo and the like.

*Edit:* Some exploring confirms that it is local to the user and machine; on a second box it works fine.  So somewhere below `~/.gconf/` a toggle must have been flipped. And yes, reset `alsamixer`, reset mute button -- all to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug or resolve this, please try the following steps:

- remove **all** users (including user 1000) from the groups `audio`, `pulse`, `pulse-access` then reboot (no user needs to be in these groups for audio!).
- Is pulseaudio running? Watch out for errors when running the following in a terminal:

  ```
  pulseaudio
  ```
- log in to the **Guest account**. Does your guest user have sound?
- From your affected user account issue the following command in a terminal:

  ```
  mv ~/.pulse/ ~/.pulse.bak/  ## removes erroneous user audio settings
  pulseaudio -k               ## restarts the sound server
  ```
- Create a new **test account** to see if sound works there.
- Do **not** run pulseaudio in [system wide mode](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide).
- Is there an audio output sink at all? Read the output of the following command:

  ```
  pacmd list-sinks
  ```
- Remove **all** attached external sound devices including speakers, reboot and then plug them back in.
- Further reading: [Ubuntu Wiki: Audio](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio)

Comment: Wonderfully precise answer, and spot on.  I had suspected `~/.gconf/`, and `~/.pulse` it was.  I now have a much happier 12-year being back to watch as watch YouTube as she wants.  Thanks!