# User session lost device settings or drivers while guest working fine

Tags: 12.10, sound, session, devices

After turning my computer today, I've noticed it getting stuck or freeze when I typed the user password. The computer was rebooted and I got the warning that there were erros and I've pressed F for automatically fix it. I remember seeing something like /home/ mount, having problems to mount.

When switching users, to guest it looks everythings working fine. My main account, there's no sound device, its not listed in the soundsettings, its completely blank the list.

Is there a way to fix this ? Is there a way to understand whats going on ?

12.10 Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224307/sound-not-working-for-uid-1003-but-working-fine-for-uid-1000)

To debug or resolve this, please try the following steps:

```
remove all users (including user 1000) from the groups audio, pulse, pulse-access then reboot (no user needs to be in these groups for audio!).

Is pulseaudio running? Watch out for errors when running the following in a terminal:

pulseaudio

log in to the Guest account. Does your guest user have sound?

From your affected user account issue the following command in a terminal:

mv ~/.pulse/ ~/.pulse.bak/  ## removes erroneous user audio settings
pulseaudio -k               ## restarts the sound server

Create a new test account to see if sound works there.

Do not run pulseaudio in system wide mode.

Is there an audio output sink at all? Read the output of the following command:

pacmd list-sinks

Remove all attached external sound devices including speakers, reboot and then plug them back in.

Further reading: Ubuntu Wiki: Audio
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.