# Rhythmbox play no sound after changing output device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, rhythmbox

Problem: Rhythmbox play no sound after changing output device. Ubuntu 12.04, i386, Rhythmbox 2.96.

How i get this:

```
 - I have connected to my laptop a bluetooth headset.
 - In sound preferences I changed output device from notebook speakers to connected headset.

 - Turned on rhythmbox to listen to music.
 - Gave my headset to my friend without turning off. 
 - Laptop turned off.
 - Laptop turned on.
 - I tried to listen to music with rhythmbox.
```

Rhythmbox behavior is as usual, but applet-indicator on drop-down sound menu freeze when i click to play If to start rhythmbox from dash it works but no sound is playing.  Other players works fine.  I tried purge
   rhythmbox, gstreamer* and install it again, but no luck. If to login
   in other user - rhythmbox works fine.

I think it is something with pulseaudio, but i don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have ended up with erroneous user settings for Pulse Audio. To restore default settings we may delete its hidden configuration directory in `~/.pulse` (or `~/.config/pulse`, depending on release version). This directory will be recreated to default settings after restarting pulseaudio.

```
mv ~/.pulse/ ~/.pulse.bak/  ## removes erroneous user audio settings
pulseaudio -k               ## restarts the sound server
```

If this does not resolve your issue please try with additional steps I gave in my answer to the following question:

- [Sound not working for uid=1003 but working fine for uid=1000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224307/sound-not-working-for-uid-1003-but-working-fine-for-uid-1000)

Comment: Thanks! after doing your instructions rhythmbox plays again on laptop loudspeakers, but another problem appeared now - when i turn in wired headset - laptop speakers became silent and no sound appeared in headset(

Comment: After rebooting everything works! Thanks again!

Comment: in 15.10 `mv .config/pulse .config/pulse.bak`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 the pulse audio settings are under `~/.config/pulse/`, hence:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.bak/
pulseaudio -k
```